# How to insert default value in JPA?

Tags: jpa

I would like to save a default value in a column when creating and updating with JPA, I tried it in the database and in java but it is not registered. IDE: NetBeans8.2 BD:Oracle11g

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjJaw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8T3t.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set the field in your entity to the default value?

```
@Entity
public class X {
    private static final String DEFAULT_EST_ALQ = "A"

    @Column(name = "EST_ALQ")
    private String estAlq = DEFAULT_EST_ALQ;

    public setEstAlg(String estAlg) {
        // overwrite default value
    }
}
```

Afaik the `columnDescription` is only used when generating tables from entities, e.g.

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
```

in persistence.xml

If you create the table via SQL the default value should be considered.

```
CREATE TABLE X(
   EST_ALQ CHAR(1 CHAR) DEFAULT 'A'
)
```

Comment: It's an example... see "e.g."

Comment: are you using EclipseLink ?

Comment: and you could eliminate the Hibernate specific part of this post by replacing that vendor specific property with `javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action`, which is standard

Comment: @BillyFrost thanks for the note, i edited the post accordingly